# Using graph-notebook to connect to Blazegraph Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter, amazon-neptune, blazegraph, graph-notebook

I tried to use **https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook** to connect to Blazegraph Database. I have verified Blazegraph is running from the following.

```
serviceURL: http://192.168.1.240:9999

Welcome to the Blazegraph(tm) Database.

Go to http://192.168.1.240:9999/bigdata/ to get started.
```

I did the following the jupyter notebook

```
%%graph_notebook_config 
{
  "host": "localhost",
  "port": 9999,
  "auth_mode": "DEFAULT",
  "iam_credentials_provider_type": "ENV",
  "load_from_s3_arn": "",
  "aws_region": "us-west-2",
  "ssl": false,
  "sparql": {
    "path": "blazegraph/namespace/foo/sparql"
  }
}
```

then do the following

```
%status
```

gives error ***{'error': JSONDecodeError('Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)',)}***

I tried to replace host with ***192.168.1.240*** and is still having the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you found a bug!

This is now fixed in https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/pull/137.